# how to generate script files with batch

Tags: batch-file

Starting from two input files, I want to generate a single output file that should be a C source or header file.

The content of the output file is more or less always the same but some parts of variable or function name.

I was thinking about to have an input file (input_1) with the skeleton of the output file I want to generate, like this

```
/**
*   @Autor:     %AUTOR_NAME%
*   @Company:   %COMPANY_NAME%
*
*   @Filename:  ble_%SERVICE_NAME%.h
*/

void ble_%SERVICE_NAME%_init(void);

[...]
```

where %AUTOR_NAME%, %COMPANY_NAME% and %SERVICE_NAME% are variables I want to get from the second input file (input_2), like this

```
SET AUTOR_NAME="Massimo Pilia"
SET COMPANY_NAME=BBAA00
SET SERVICE_NAME=security
```

In order to obtain an output file named "ble_security.h" containing this:

```
/**
*   @Autor:     Massimo Pilia
*   @Company:   BBAA00
*
*   @Filename:  ble_security.h
*/

void ble_security_init(void);

[...]
```

How can I do this with a batch file?

Thanks in advance
Massimo Pilia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is make good use of Delayed Expansion feature. To do that, enclose the variable names in input_1 file between exclamation marks instead of percent signs:

```
/**
*   @Autor:     !AUTOR_NAME!
*   @Company:   !COMPANY_NAME!
*
*   @Filename:  ble_!SERVICE_NAME!.h
*/

void ble_!SERVICE_NAME!_init(void);

[...]
```

And then use this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load variable definitions from file 2
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input_2.txt) do %%a

rem Process lines of file 1, append a "number:" to all lines
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" input_1.txt') do (

   rem Get the line *including* !variable! replacements
   set "line=%%a"

   rem Remove leading number, show the rest *including* empty lines
   echo(!line:*:=!

)) > ble_security.h
```

You may also remove the quotes in the definitions in input_1 file; otherwise, the quotes will be included in the variable value.

Output example:

```
/**
*   @Autor:     Massimo Pilia
*   @Company:   BBAA00
*
*   @Filename:  ble_security.h
*/

void ble_security_init(void);

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input_2) do %%a
(
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input_1) do call set line=%%a&echo(!line!
)>ble_security.h
```

Although you'd need to remove the quotes in `input_2`

OR

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input_2) do set "%%a"
(
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input_1) do call set line=%%a&echo(!line!
)>ble_security.h
```

And you could then remove all the `set`s in `input_2`

Note that this will delete any empty lines or lines starting `;` but will be fine with a line of spaces

---

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input_2) do set "%%a"
(
 for /f "tokens=1,2delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" input_1') do call set line=%%b&ECHO(!line!
)>ble_security.h
```

should allow empty lines but will delete any leading `]` in any line

Comment: It was just what I was looking for...thank you very much. Now I have to discover something to leave the blank lines in the output file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use echo to send the text to a file.

```
@echo off
echo /** > %outputfile%
echo * @Autor: %AUTOR_NAME% >> %outputfile%
echo * @Company:   %COMPANY_NAME% >> %outputfile%
[...]
```

I am assuming that you have already set the outputfile variable.
@echo off turns off printing of each command to the console but it can still print to a file.
A single '>' will overwrite the existing file, a double '>>' appends to it.

Comment: That was my first thought. However I thing it could be complicated to modify each line if I wanted to change something, or if the size of the code I want to generate increases.
Anyway...Thanks a lot for your time.